Forms to Sharepoint through Power Automate
I'm getting an error message for blank fields. I would like to have the automation create a Zero (0) in the blank fields so that the Flow does not fail. What's the easiest way to do this?

set the default value of the field in the SharePoint list settings. then it will show up in the Create Item interface in Power Automate.
